# how to get the existing collection in mongodb using mongose- Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my mongodb i already had a collection and document
[image]

Now, i want to use this collection in my node-js using mongoose. how we do this.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const adminLogin = new schema({
name: { type: String, required: true },
password: { type: String, required: true }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("adminDetails", adminLogin)
```

while doing this it is creating new collection. Unable to use the existing collection.

Comment: I see no issue. Are you sure u used the corrent mongodb URI and the same database?

Comment: yes I've used correct URL

Answer (score 0):

1. At first you need to make a GET method Router in your jsFile.

like this

```
app.get("/mainData", async (req, res) => {
  const menuInfo = await Nutrients.find({});
  res.json(menuInfo);
});
```

2. You can set and use VSCode extension "thunderClient"!

like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAz8e.jpg)

3. setting your request method and URI endpoint

(when you user GET method to get some data in your case, you don't need to write something in request body)

4. Then, you can see your data on the 'response part' as an Object Data.
5. If you want to use your data on Front side on your Project, you can use like this!

(in my case, I used jQuery. )

```
function menu_show() {
$('#result_list').empty()
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/mainData',     //you need to write same url with your no3.
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        let rows = response['menus']

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            let menuName = rows[i]['menuName']
            console.log(menuName)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my answer. Let me know if you've solved it!

Comment: route.get('/adminLogin', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        console.log(request.body)
        const post = await adminDetails.find({})
        response.json(post);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

Response is coming as null

Answer (score 0):

[image: Structure in mongodb]

the image 1 is the structure in the MongoDB. I want to read the data from that collection, below is the code using and the URL and output in post man.

```
route.get('/adminLogin', (request, response) => {
  const data =  adminDetails.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.json(result)
    }
  })
})
```

http://localhost:5000/admin/adminLogin

[image: Response in postman]